# How to enable paging in Flutter GridView?

Tags: gridview, dart, flutter, paging

I'm new to dart and I know this might be simple. But, I was not able to find a simple answer on, How do I enable paging in Flutter's `GridView`. I'm from a swift background where this can be achieved by just one line. `collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true`. Similarly how can I achieve this in dart?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use PageView instead of GridView. Refer following code.

```
new PageView.builder(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  itemCount: item.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
    return new Container();
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Frankenstein explained perfectly moreover i will add some additional information regarding moving pageView to specific page.

1)Add PageController to your PageView like below.

```
`final _pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);`
```

2)Call JumpPage to navigate to your required page like below.

```
`_pageController.jumpToPage(3 - 1);`
```